# SQL Server Express LocalDb doesn't work on machine without VisualStudio, SSMS works

Tags: c#, sql-server-express, localdb, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to deploy a C# application to my target machine and I keep getting errors that I couldn't log into the SQL Server. After much ado, I think I have determined the source of problem but I don't know the cause.

On my development machine, app works fine. On a second machine I was using it works too, that machine does have VS on it. Target machine does not have VS, I only installed SQL Server Express w/ Tools. The specific error I'm getting is:

> Login failed for user 'blah'

I'm using SQL Server authentication. So it appears that something is getting installed with VS that is not with Express only. Also, SSMS works fine on target machine.

I'm not an SQL guru and all the internet searching has yielded this same problem but never really found a solution that worked for me.

Connection String:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder myBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
myBuilder.DataSource = @"(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB";
myBuilder.InitialCatalog = @"C:\CSI\MOTOR_TESTER.MDF";
myBuilder.UserID = "User";
myBuilder.Password = "pw";
myConnection.ConnectionString = myBuilder.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: UPDATE: The target machine logs onto a domain. I currently have two user accounts, one with local admin rights, the other doesn't. Let's call them adminuser and reguser. If I login with adminuser, I can connect to db from app. If I login as reguser, it fails.

Comment: check if the reguser has login rights under the Security/Logins section using SSMS. If not just create a login for reguser so that MSSQL can authenticate you.

Comment: If I run my app as reguser, no go. Right>Click Run As Administrator works. I think I see where this is going but I don't know what knobs to twiddle in SSMS to get this to work for reguser.

Comment: @objectNotFound There is login for reguser in that section.

Comment: if it works when logged-in as RegUser (but have to Run As Administrator) then the issue is not with MSSQL . It is Windows that is preventing you. So if you need you app to run without having to do Run-as administrator then try granting full rights from Windows Explorer for your .exe file that your app compiles to. Right click File from Windows Explorer --> properties --> security --> edit --> add --> pick RegUser --> ok.

Comment: @objectNotFound I don't think it's that because reguser does have Full Control to the folder that the exe resides in. Also, the app does run as reguser, the SQL login part of the app fails.

Comment: you need that explicit grant IMO (from memory.. I cant try it right now) ... so just try it if there is no harm :)

Comment: @objectNotFound OK I tried that, and also giving full control to the mdf and ldf files. I even made reguser an admin and nothing worked. So I'm asking IT to make reguser a local admin just like adminuser. However they do it must be different than me granting with my local admin account.